# Does a linear map exist such that the kernel is a subspace and the image too? (Explanation needed)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

"Let $V$ be a finite vector space, and $U_1$ and $U_2$ $\subseteq$ V subspaces.
Is it true that

there exist a linear map $\psi$ ∶ $V$ → $V$ with ker($\psi$) =  $U_1$  and im($\psi$) = $U_2$?"

The answer is no. My question: Why?

Would be very thankful for a short and simple explanation. Or a hint.

[The problem is, I thought I had constructed (if you can call it that) a linear map with these charateristics and even thought it worked (I checked with the dimension formula, and that fit). Plus, for the exam we not only needed to state it's false, but also write a simple proof - which wasn't part of the past exams, so I can't just look up there.
(It's surely a very easy question, but I'm a first semester and sometimes can't wrap my head around these things immediately. I think I'm just missing a key fact there.)]

Comment: Consider $U_1=U_2$.

Comment: One restriction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Consider $U_1 = V$. Then $\psi$ is necessarily the $0$-map, hence $U_2$ can only be $\{0\}$. So not all combinations are possible.